# Filtering out NULL values in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to figure out how to get rid of these NULL values. I have written a query that is supposed to only return orders that were shipped in 1994 but I get a couple NULLs. I think it has something to do with how I have joined my tables but I am not sure.

I solved this issue but using the following query. What I actually needed to do was add 10 days to the order date to get the `ShippedDate` result.

```
SELECT    
    Orders.OrderID,
    Products.ProductID,
    Customers.CompanyName,
    (OrderDetails.Quantity * Products.UnitPrice) AS OrderCost,
    FORMAT(DATEADD(DAY, 10,Orders.OrderDate), 'MMM dd yyyy') AS ShippedDate
FROM            
    Customers 
INNER JOIN
    Orders ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID 
INNER JOIN
    OrderDetails ON Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID 
INNER JOIN
    Products ON OrderDetails.ProductID = Products.ProductID
WHERE 
    YEAR (OrderDate) >= ('1994') 
    AND (OrderDetails.Quantity * Products.UnitPrice) >= '2500'
ORDER BY 
    CompanyName
```

[image]

Comment: Where are you getting the NULLS; which fields. Do you have sample data?

Comment: Oops. I added a screen shot.

Comment: Does order 11008 have a shipped date? Also, you are requesting orders since 1994

Comment: Your WHERE condition guarantees that OrderDate is not null.   But the query is returning the value of ShippedDate.   Perhaps there are orders made since 1994 with no ship date.

Comment: I have figured it out, I actually misread the question I was trying to answer. The "ShippedDate" column is actually supposed to be the "OrderDate" plus 10 days.

Comment: Am I blind? I still don't see the `nulls` you're referring to in the screenshot.

Comment: @Xedni - no you are not blind, I actually edited this post because it came down to a simple error on my part.

Comment: Ah, didn't see that. Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

You are filtering by one columns and showing the other one. Shouldn't you be showing the same one? Maybe the solution is like:

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID,
       Products.ProductID,
       Customers.CompanyName,
       (OrderDetails.Quantity * Products.UnitPrice) AS OrderCost,
       FORMAT(Orders.ShippedDate, 'MMM dd yyyy') AS ShippedDate
  FROM Customers 
  INNER JOIN Orders ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
  INNER JOIN OrderDetails ON Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID
  INNER JOIN Products ON OrderDetails.ProductID = Products.ProductID
  WHERE YEAR (Orders.ShippedDate) >= ('1994') -- CHANGED COLUMN HERE!
  ORDER BY CompanyName;
```